# How to make Navigation Bar visible using Webview frame = self.view.bounds?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, webview

my problem is that **Navigation Bar is behind my WebView** because its frame is self.view.bounds, and the app don't shows the Navigation Bar. If I ignore the WebView frame = self.view.bounds, my WebView doesn't fit the screen on iPhone 8 device simulation.

How can I make my WebView fit the right, left and bottom screen sides and show my Navigation Bar on the top ???

I tried modifying my WebView **Content Mode**, but nothing happens...

The **Navigation Bar is working fine**, and the **back and refresh buttons too**. The problem is making the WebView fit the screen using myWebView.frame=self.view.bounds the Navigation Bar hides behind myWebView :(

My code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myWebView.delegate = self

    let myURL=URL(string:"https://www.google.com")
    let requestObj = URLRequest(url:myURL!)
    myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj)
    self.view.addSubview(myWebView)

    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
    URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0


    myWebView.scalesPageToFit = true;
    myWebView.frame=self.view.bounds;
```

[my storyboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItZTi.png)

Thanks ;)

Comment: Helps if you show your code otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: Oki, there is it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem. What I did is:

1.- Select my **View Controller**.

2.- On Menu click on **Editor** > **Embed In** > **Navigation Controller**

Xcode add a **Navigation Controller** and on **View Controller** was added a **Navigation Item**. On this Navigation Item you can add a **Bar Button Item**, for example used as a Back Button or Refresh Button.

Doing all before, I still use:

```
myWebView.scalesPageToFit = true;
myWebView.frame=self.view.bounds;
```

and my WebView fit to all screens using different devices and the navigation bar fits perfectly :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let navBarHeight: CGFloat = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0


    title = "Webview"
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    let webView = UIWebView()
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(webView)

    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: navBarHeight).isActive = true
    webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://apple.com")!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I don´t have a Navigation Controller, is just a Navigation Bar (see image on my question)

Comment: so if you have created a navbar through Storyboard, maybe you can create an IBOutlet and find the height of the component. Or put the height value in the code instead of navBarHeight

Comment: I don´t think the problem is the navbar, maybe I didn´t explain it very well. The problem is the webview when the FRAME property is SELF.VIEW.BOUNDS because of this the navbar hides behind.

Comment: Show what you get at runtime

Comment: Is there a way to let the webview FRAME = SELF.VIEW.BOUNDS (to fit any screen size) and let the navbar at the top of the screen ???

Comment: Embed the view in a navigationController

Comment: At runtime I see the complete webview that fits any screen size but without the navbar.

Comment: Use a navigation controller instead. After you can customize the navBar as you did